# s3_direct_upload is not working in production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

In Rails 4.0.2, I am using `s3_direct_upload` and `aws-sdk` gems for file uploads for s3 bucket directly. In development environment it is working fine but in production environment it is throwing an error like below,

```
ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of nil into String)
```

In views,

```
<%= s3_uploader_form :callback_url=>create_cv_url, :id=> "s3_uploader", :key=> "cv_uploads/{unique_id}/${filename}",
  :key_starts_with=> "cv_uploads/", :callback_param=> "cv[direct_upload_url]", :max_file_size=> 1.megabytes,
  :expiration=> 24.hours.from_now.utc.iso8601 do %>

   <%= file_field_tag :file, multiple: true, :max_file_size => 1.megabytes, accept: 'application/pdf application/msword application/rtf application/doc application/docx' %>

<% end %>

<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
<div id="upload_{%=o.unique_id%}" class="upload">
  <h5 class="mt1">Please Wait. <span style="color: #5f6fa0;"> {%=o.name%} </span>is processing...</h5>
  <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" style="width: 0%;"></div></div>
</div>
```

Here, the issue is mainly pointing to `s3_uploader_form` line(in views).

This feature is fully referred from http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and

In paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
 url:                  :s3_domain_url,
 path:                 ':class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename',
 storage:              :s3,
 s3_credentials:       Rails.configuration.aws,
 s3_permissions:       :private,
 s3_protocol:          'http'
)

require 'paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector'
 module Paperclip
 class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
   def spoofed?
    false
   end
 end
end
```

In aws.rb

```
require 'aws-sdk'
# Rails.configuration.aws is used by AWS, Paperclip, and S3DirectUpload
Rails.configuration.aws = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("#   {Rails.root}/config/aws.yml")).result)[Rails.env].symbolize_keys!
AWS.config(:logger=> Rails.logger)
AWS.config(Rails.configuration.aws)
```

In s3_direct_upload.rb

```
S3DirectUpload.config do |c|
 c.access_key_id     = Rails.configuration.aws[:access_key_id]
 c.secret_access_key = Rails.configuration.aws[:secret_access_key]
 c.bucket            = Rails.configuration.aws[:bucket]
 c.region            = "s3"
end
```

Is it because of configuration issue in production environment? Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solve it adding the file config.yml with my S3 credentials:

**RailsApp/config.yml**

```
  # Fill in your AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key
  # http://aws.amazon.com/security-credentials
  access_key_id: xxxxxx
  secret_access_key: xxxxxxx
```

More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsRuby/latest/DeveloperGuide/ruby-dg-setup.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its working after changing aws.yml file

Answer (score 2):

The code seems ok. As [skozz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957253/skozz) mentioned, one of the issue may be with your configuration keys that may be not assigned properly. Please check aws production keys in "/config/aws.yml".

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering the same, by following this [link](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload). The thing is that I've added the initializers, but I needed to restart rails (it was running but not refreshed).

Answer (score 0):

Executing this command worked for me. `figaro heroku:set -e production`